# Facing issue while converting blank ('') to toDouble in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am facing issue while converting blank ('') to toDouble in mongodb

my query is as

```
{$expr: {$gte: [{$toDouble: "$rating"}, 1.5]}}
```

For getting result which has rating **GreaterthanOREqual** to 1.5, but some rows has **rating:''**
So getting error- Failed to parse number '' in $convert with no onError value: Empty string[image]

Answer (score 0):

could exclude the rating "" records

```
db.getCollection('your-collection-name').find(
    {"rating" : {$ne: ""}, $expr: {$gte: [{$toDouble: "$rating"}, 1.5]}}
)
```

or include records having a [type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) double

```
db.getCollection('your-collection-name').find(
    {"rating" : {$type: 1}, $expr: {$gte: [{$toDouble: "$rating"}, 1.5]}}
)
```

Comment: This query will exclude record which having rating as '', i want consider '' as '0'

Comment: It can be done with aggreation to replace rating of '' to 0 .
But it will not satisfy $gte 1.5 expression.
Is some additional condition that have been excluded for simplifying the question?

Comment: I have done API changes to store default rating as '0' instead of '', it is working for me now